# Mostrar el mes en texto de una fecha formato YYYY-MM-dd de un array en JS

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

estoy desarrollando un sistema en el cual implemento JS para mostrar las fechas de una publicación pero simplemente quiero mostrar en texto el mes en el cual el artículo fue publicado.

Por ejemplo: "2023-08-16 16:22:30"--> "Agosto"

```
function LoadData(){
 $.ajax({
 url: 'view.php',
 type: "POST",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  $('#MyTable div').empty();
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   var commentId = data[i].iddisc;
    if(data[i].parent_comment == 0){       

     var row = $('<div class="info-box"><p id="date-p"> 'data[i].datePubli'</p></div> ');
    
    }
   }
 }
}
```

},

En donde *data[i].datePubli* trae el valor *datetime*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción seria pasar la fecha a un objeto Date() y luego utilizar el metodo toLocaleString() de JavaScript

```
function LoadData(){
 $.ajax({
 url: 'view.php',
 type: "POST",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  $('#MyTable div').empty();
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   var commentId = data[i].iddisc;
    if(data[i].parent_comment == 0){       
     var date = new Date(data[i].datePubli);
     var month = date.toLocaleString('es-ES', { month: 'long' });
     var row = $('<div class="info-box"><p id="date-p">' + month + '</p></div>');
    }
   }
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba, lo había probado pero me faltaba el date.toLocaleString